# Rails Acts As Tenant error using current_tenant in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-tenant

I'm using `Acts_as_tenant`. The doc says `"adds a handy helper to your controllers current_tenant, containing the current tenant object"`.

But, I'd like to access the current tenant in a model.  The `Tenant` model contains a column - `request_closed`.

I wish this worked:

```
class Worequest < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_tenant(:tenant)
  closedcode = current_tenant.request_closed
  scope :notclosed, where("statuscode_id < ?", closedcode )
```

I also tried:

```
closedcode = ActsAsTenant.current_tenant.request_closed
and
closedcode = self.tenant.request_closed
```

But, I get:

```
undefined local variable or method `current_tenant'
```

Is there a way to access the current_tenant in a model?

Thanks for the help!

UPDATE1

I thought this would work - it does in development but not on my Heroku staging server.

Application Controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  protect_from_forgery

  set_current_tenant_by_subdomain(:tenant, :subdomain)

  before_filter :set_tenant_codes
    def set_tenant_codes
      $requestclosed = current_tenant.request_closed
    end
```

Request Controller:

```
  scope :notclosed, where("statuscode_id < ?", $requestclosed )
```

????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked:

```
  def self.closed
    where("statuscode_id = ?", ActsAsTenant.current_tenant.request_closed)
  end
```